# fixed points of an affine transformation is unique iff $1 \notin SP(\vec{f} )$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, affine-geometry

> Let $f$ be Affine transformation from $E$ to $E$ (always we assume it finite dimensional ) and $\overrightarrow{f}$  is the linear mapping associated to $f$. Then the map $f$ has a unique fixed point     if and only if $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $\overrightarrow{f}$
>
> Proof :
> If $f$ has a unique fixed point, according to $7.2$ , all of its fixed points is a
> affine subspace direction $\{\vec{0}\}=\operatorname{Ker}(\overrightarrow{f}-Id_{\vec{E}})$, so $1$ is not unique value of  $\overrightarrow{f}$.

the origine of text

[image]

i don't understand why $\operatorname{Ker}(\overrightarrow{f}-Id_{\vec{E}})$ equal $\{\vec{0}\}$ and after that why we get $1\notin \operatorname{Sp}(f)$

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single point is an affine space with tangent space (i.e., direction) of dimension$~0$. The result 7.2 apparently says that if there are any fixed points, they form an affine space with direction $\ker(\vec f-Id)$. So if there is a unique fixed point, that subspace must be of dimension$~0$, which means precisely that $1$ is not an eigenvalue of$~\vec f$ (for if it were, its eigenspace would be $\ker(\vec f-Id)$ and of nonzero dimension).

Comment: yes The result 7.2 apparently says that if there are any fixed points, they form an affine space with direction $\ker(\vec f-Id)$. could you add some explaintion mathematically not just by words please

Comment: @Educ Ça alors... So you want me to explain, but not just by words. Words are what mathematics is all about (well, not exclusively...). I suppose you want more formulas, then? But all the formulas you need are there. It is really about understanding that the direction is on one hand $\ker(\vec f-Id)$ because of 7.2, and and the other hand $\{\vec0\}$ that is what the direction of a single point is; so the two are equal. What is not clear about that?

Comment: do you have link explain " A single point is an affine space with tangent space (i.e., direction) of dimension 0" in french " Thanks for ur time

Comment: No link, but I can do French. L'ensemble des points fixes est point tout seul, qui forme un espace affine de direction $\{\vec0\}$, c'est-à-dire dont la direction est un espace vectoriel de dimension$~0$. D'après 7.2 cette direction $\{\vec0\}$ est égale à $\ker(\vec f-1Id)$, ce qui veut dire $\vec f$ n'a pas de valeur propre $\lambda=1$ (sinon $\ker(\vec f-1Id)$ serait l'espace propre correspondant, et donc de dimension${}>0$).

Answer (score 1):

The set of fixed points of $f$ is the kernel of $f - Id$, and the latter is indeed an affine subspace with direction $\text{Ker}(\vec{f} - Id)$. Since by hypothesis there is only one fixed point, the affine subspace is reduced to a point and so must be $\text{Ker}(\vec f - Id)$. Saying that $1$ is not a proper value of $f$ is exactly the same as saying that $f-Id$ only vanishes in $0$.

Comment: can you elaborate more not just by words but mathematically please